# How can I improve hierarchy of information?

Tags: interface, information-architecture, dashboard

Any insights / ideas as to how I would be able to improve the information hierarchy on the screenshot below? The headliner's data and questions data (Development / Company's benchmark / Comments) are the same size... I wonder how I would be able to make it more appealing?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some quick suggestions:

- The description text on the tabs at the top could be subordinated; try a smaller font. Once users have an idea of what the tabs mean, they won't need to refer to the descriptions again.
- The categories in each question section heading (Ease of Use, Expectation settings, etc.) could be visually stronger. Experiment with slightly larger and heavier fonts.
- Try indenting the questions under each section to make them look like they belong to their respective headings.

Comment: Thank you Stacy for your valuable insights. I will use a bold font as headlines. Additionally, the tabs grouping it's a new company concept - hence I added a description for now - the users/clients have to acknowledge the grouping of the questions within the survey. I have an additional question: Do you have some idea how can I differentiate the data visualization between a section heading and questions?  At the moment the data  (Development / Company's benchmark / Comments) has the same size. It's 18 px...I really got stuck with it.

Comment: Taking a cue from Material Design, you could use color on the active section heading to make it look more selected -- either by adding a shading color to the background, or a color to the text. Also, I think the "zebra stripes" on the questions are a little strong and pop out ahead of the header; you could look at removing them and see if the questions are still distinct enough.

Answer (score 0):

- indenting and numbering questions
- the columns (development comments and company) should also be visible a bit more strongly

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to focus on improving visual hierarchy in your design

- make sure there's sufficient different between sizes and weights in your typeface
- use white space to make sure there's no overcrowding of information

[https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/topics/visual-hierarchy#:~:text=Visual%20hierarchy%20is%20the%20principle,guide%20them%20to%20desired%20actions](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/topics/visual-hierarchy#:%7E:text=Visual%20hierarchy%20is%20the%20principle,guide%20them%20to%20desired%20actions).